# Google Chrome extension execute script not executing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my first attempt at a Google Chrome extension. All this is supposed to do is make a monster energy can go across the screen when you are loading something.

**Manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Monster Energy Progress Bar",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A fun Monster Energy-themed progress bar for your browser.",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "activeTab", "<all_urls>"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "assets/logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Background.js**

```
// background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
      if (details.type === "main_frame" && details.method === "GET") {
        console.log('All was well');
        chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function(tab) {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !tab) {
            console.error("Error getting tab:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
            return;
          }
  
          console.log('Executing script');
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: "contentScript.js"
          });
          console.log('Shouldve executed');
        });
      }
      console.log('All was NOT well');
    },
    { urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"] },
    ["blocking"]
  );
```

**contentScript**

```
// contentScript.js
function injectMonsterEnergyBar() {
    console.log('starting injectingMonsterEnergyBar');
    const progressBar = document.createElement("div");
    progressBar.id = "monster-energy-bar";
    progressBar.style.position = "fixed";
    progressBar.style.top = "100px";
    progressBar.style.left = "100px";
    progressBar.style.width = "100px";
    progressBar.style.height = "100px";
    progressBar.style.background = `url('/assets/monster1.png') repeat-x`;
    document.body.appendChild(progressBar);
  
    let width = 0;
    const interval = setInterval(function () {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        progressBar.remove();
      } else {
        width++;
        progressBar.style.width = width + "%";
      }
    }, 50);
  }
  
  // Add this line to trigger the function when the content script is injected
  injectMonsterEnergyBar();
```

Not a whole lot to it. The problem is that every time I try to test this what my console looks like is that it prints "Executing script" and "Shouldve executed" but never prints "starting injectingMonsterEnergyBar". Which leads me to believe that the contentScript is never executed.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: 1) Remove `Background.js` and `background` from manifest.json. 2) Add web_accessible_resources and use chrome.runtime.getURL for assets as shown in the documentation. 3) See also [how to run content scripts right after installation](/q/10994324).

Comment: @wOxxOm could you explain why I need to do this a little bit? I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Well, there's just no need for webRequest and this is how extensions work.

Comment: @wOxxOm I made your changes and it works now. Sorry it took me a while but I understand. Why don't you write a proper answer so I can get you credit?